# Should I always use webservice?

Tags: php, web-services, client-server

HI all,

I am designing an client - server application system. The Server provide 2 features: upload and download images. The clients (maybe Iphone, Android, WP7, ...) use these features to provide to end-users.

At this time, I can design the server as web-pages (such as upload.php, download.php) as well as webservices. Both ways work fine for me.

My question is: which one I use webservices or web-pages technical for my designing? And why?

Thanks.

Comment: when you say webservices do you mean SOAP based webservice?

Comment: yes, I am building SOAP based webservice.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest with you, using something like SOAP for this seems like a lot of unnecessary effort.  You can very easily accomplish this using form encoded data and the right query string parameters without going through the trouble of building SOAP envelopes and writing all of the XML. Granted, the system I described is very close to a REST webservice, so I suppose it depends on what you mean by "webservice."  Either way though, given relatively simple system you've outlined, I don't think something like SOAP will give you a very good return on your investment.